# What is the difference between useMemo and useCallback in case of memoizing a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-usecallback

As we know that `useMemo` is used to memoize a value and `useCallback` is used to memoize a function. When it comes to all value except function then I use `useMemo` else `useCallback` but I wonder what if the value is a function so would memoizing a function using `useCallback` and `useMemo` are same or not.

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/romantic-cdn-n7gyd8?file=/src/App.js:4,1-35,1)

```
function Diff(props) {
  const { value } = props;

  const memoizedFnUsingMemo = useMemo(() => () => value + value, [value]);
  const memoizedFnUsingCallback = useCallback(() => value + value, [value]);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{memoizedFnUsingMemo()}</h1>
      <h1>{memoizedFnUsingCallback()}</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function changeCounter(change) {
    setCounter((c) => c + change);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>counter: {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => changeCounter(1)}> increment </button>
      <button onClick={() => changeCounter(-1)}> decrement </button>

      <Diff value={counter} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear about this. Both are equivalent. With `useCallback` you do not have to write an extra wrapper and that just provides more code readability imo.

From the docs:

> Memoizing functions is common enough that React has a built-in Hook specifically for that. Wrap your functions into useCallback instead of useMemo to avoid having to write an extra nested function. The two examples above are completely equivalent. The only benefit to useCallback is that it lets you avoid writing an extra nested function inside. It doesn’t do anything else.

[Link](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo#memoizing-a-function)